# does there exist a function $f\in C_0^P(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq I, f(x_0)=1$ and $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\leq 1?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Fix a natural number $p\geq 1.$
Let $C_0^p(\mathbb{R})$ be a collection of all continous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that its $i$th derivatives are continuous for all $0\leq i \leq p$ and $f$ vanishes at infinity, that is, for every $\varepsilon>0,$ the set $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \geq \varepsilon \}$ is compact.

Let $\text{supp}(f) = \overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)\neq 0 \}}.$

> **Question**: Given any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and any open set $I$ containing $x_0,$ does there exist a function $f\in C_0^P(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq I, f(x_0)=1$ and $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\leq 1?$

My attempt:

By applying Urysohn's lemma on complement of $I$ and an open neighbourhood $U \subseteq I$ of $x,$ there exists a continous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ such that $f$ is $0$ outside of $I$ and $1$ on $U.$
It remains to check whether $f$ has continuous $i$th derivatives for all $0\leq i \leq p.$

I think that $f$ may not be an element of $C_0^p(\mathbb{R}).$
I believe that something need to be done on $f$ but I do not know what should be done.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @EricTowers: I apologize for not including my working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the problem: make a bump function that is sufficiently smooth.  By "bump function", we mean a function that is zero off of $I$, increases up to $1$ and then back down to $0$ on the two connected components of $I \smallsetminus U,$ and is $1$ on $U$.

How can I turn a $C_0^k$ function into a $C_0^{k+1}$ function?

> Integrate it.

But if I integrate a "bump", I get a "step", so we don't get back down to $0$ as we leave $I$.  How does this give me a smoother bump?

> Make two steps -- one going up, one going down -- and multiply them (since products are at least as continuous as the multiplicands).  Suppose $f$ is a "bump" that is $0$ outside $I$.  We find $u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ is a step up and $d(x) = \int_{x}^\infty f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ is a step down.  Then $u(x) d(x)$ is a bump and is at least as continuous as $d$ and $u$.  It's also zero where either $u$ or $d$ is, so we haven't increased the support when we made this new bump.
>
> If you scale $u$ or $d$ so that the product is $1$ at $x_0$, you get your supremum condition.

So the strategy is ...?

> Start with the result from Urysohn's lemma, a $C_0^0(\mathbb{R})$ bump function.  For each $n \in [1,p] \subset \mathbb{Z}$, construct the $C_0^n(\mathbb{R})$ bump function via the two steps described above coming from the $C^0_0$ bump.  This gives family of bumps of increasing smoothness.  Each has support in $I$.  At each step, verify that the bump comes up to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a function $f_0 \in C^p$ with support on $[-1,1]$ such that $0 \le f_0(x) \le 1 = f_0(0)$ for all $x$. For example, if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables on $[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$ and $n > p$, then the density function of $X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n$ will work. Then set $f(x) = f_0((x-x_0)/\delta)$ where $\delta$ is sufficiently small.